# How to accept password in cx_Oracle which contains '@' symbol

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

Below is the code I am executing on python.

```
 import cx_Oracle
 oracle_url = user/p@ssword@hostname:1521/db_service
 cx_Oracle.connect(oracle_url)
```

It gives error : ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tried solutions (which work on powershell or CMD):

1. Adding "Quotes" surrounding my password did not helped.
2. Adding \"Quotes\" also does not work.

Comment: What happens if you replace the ‘@‘ with the URL or percent encoded value: ‘%40’?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the below?

If SID is used,

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('server', 'port', 'sid')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='username', password='password', dsn=dsn_tns)
```

or if ServiceName is used

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('server', 'port', service_name='service_name')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='username', password='password', dsn=dsn_tns)
```